# Applying Directives to Root With or Without <Directive />?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

When you put "bare" things like `ServerSignature Off` or `Require all denied` into httpd.conf without enclosing `<Directive>` how is it interpreted? Is it applied to the Server Root?

Is this:

```
ServerSignature Off
Require all denied
```

the same as this:

```
<Directory />
    ServerSignature Off
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

What is the recommended practice? Most people I know put things that concern the root without the `<Directory />` but it makes sense for consistency to open the `<Directory />` and put everything that concerns the root in it. Then later on override what you need on a more specific level `<Directory /path/to/your/folder>`.

Comment: You state that "it makes sense for consistency" ... I'd say that is a subjective view. If you feel better then sure, go for it. But one could likewise reason that it makes sense to have directives meant to get applied globally _not_ contained within anything to separate them from those directives limited by the container they are implemented in.

Comment: You are right. It is a personal decision. So, the conclusion is that these two ways both apply to the server root?

Comment: Careful! `<Directory />` does _not_ refer to the folder set with the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directive, but to the _absolute_ path within the server side file system. That is a _huge_ difference! For file system based directives it should come out the same, whether you place directive inside such a `Directive` container or outside. For other directives it might make a difference, not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating, the answer is yes, both apply to the server root.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).